# How to Put Random Numbers into Loop in Fortran

Tags: loops, random, fortran

I have the following code:

```
program outputdata   
implicit none

  real, dimension(100) :: x, y  
  real, dimension(100) :: p, q
  integer :: i  

  ! data  
  do i=1,100  
      x(i) = i * 0.1 
      y(i) = sin(x(i)) * (1-cos(x(i)/3.0))  
  end do  

  ! output data into a file 
  open(1, file = 'data1.dat', status = 'new')  
  do i=1,100  
      write(1,*) x(i), y(i)   
  end do  

  close(1) 

end program outputdata
```

I would like to write a very similar code but which uses a string of random numbers instead of 1-100 sequentially. I have found these codes for generating random number sequences:

```
real :: r(5)

call random_seed()
call random_number(r)
```

but I cannot seem to figure out how to combine the codes to input the random number vector into the loop.

Comment: Are you seeking random values that are increments of 0.1, or do you want "continuous" floating point values?  (Scare quotes because, yes, it's got finite precision on a computer.)

Comment: What do you want your random numbers to look like? Uniform, random permutation of all integers, random selection with/without repeats, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran does not have an intrinsic integer random number generator. But writing one is easy:

```
module random_mod

    implicit none

contains

    function getRandInt(lowerBound,upperBound) result(randInt)
        use iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: lowerBound,upperBound
        real(RK)            :: dummy
        integer             :: randInt
        call random_number(dummy)
        randInt = lowerBound + floor(dummy*(upperBound-lowerBound+1))
    end function getRandInt

end module random_mod

program random_prog
    
    use random_mod, only: getRandInt
    implicit none
    
    integer, parameter :: NSIM = 100
    integer :: i, Index(NSIM)
    
    do i = 1, NSIM
        Index(i) = getRandInt(-NSIM,NSIM)
    end do
    
    write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "Random Indices in [",-NSIM,",",NSIM,"] :"
    write(*,"(10(g0,:,' '))") Index 

end program random_prog
```

The above code yields:

```sh
$gfortran -std=gnu *.f90 -o main
$main
Random Indices in [ -100 , 100 ] :
-97 -37 35 86 -91 27 -33 60 -58 -70 
61 22 -70 40 43 29 9 -37 74 -21 
39 -19 96 -31 -46 41 24 0 59 -4 
-83 -54 96 9 -80 -44 44 -4 25 45 
15 -83 -45 -49 -95 -47 25 -95 84 79 
81 -42 -6 -40 95 -63 66 47 -77 51 
13 -17 73 -48 -80 23 -75 79 -33 -79 
69 -52 61 -31 -95 -4 79 85 81 87 
-16 87 -14 -43 -25 56 65 -33 -99 83 
84 -36 26 20 -22 -99 33 -95 -48 75
```

In your code, all you need to do is to replace the index `i` with the function call `getRandInt(lowerBound = 1, upperBound = 100)` to get a random index instead of `i`.

Comment: Why is the type casting `real(upperBound-lowerBound,kind=RK)` needed?

Comment: It's worth noting that `nint` [does not lend itself](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23057399/2) to uniform distribution.

Comment: @jack Thanks for the note, I have removed it.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the note. But using `floor` will not result in a closed interval, from `lowerBound` to and including the `upperBound`. I think that is the common definition of discrete uniform numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution

Comment: @francescalus Do you mean that the resulting discrete distribution would not be uniform? In that case, the code has to be modified.

Comment: Yes, if using `nint` then the lower and upper numbers have half the probability of being sampled than the numbers in the middle. [0,0.5) mapping to 0, [0.5,1.5) mapping to 1, ... [n-0.5, n) mapping to n.

Comment: @francescalus I think your argument is correct if you meant the resulting distribution is not uniform. I have corrected the answer accordingly. Thanks for the sharp observation.